# Enable ES6 syntax in an AngularJS project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, gulp, eslint

I've a big Angular project with gulp and other tools configured (I don't know these tools), this project seems not to support ES6 syntax (.map/.filter/destructuring/etc.) even if the Node version I'm currently running on (10.13.0) does.

For example, when I use `.map`, on `gulp serve` I got this error:

```
internal/streams/legacy.js:57
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
      ^
Error: Error in parsing: "anthea\gestioneservizi\manutenzioneveicoli\listamanutenzioni\nuovamanutenzione\nuovaorganizzazionepianificazione.controller.js", Line 337: Unexpected token =>
```

Any suggestion how to enable this syntax or how can I give you more details about project?

Comment: `.map` and `.filter` themselves aren't ES6 syntax (just regular method syntax, and those methods have been around for a while), but using *arrow functions* as the callbacks is. You could just use vanilla functions.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Arrow functions have been supported in node since like v6.

Comment: @Cully yes, and are supported in the Node version the OP's using, but evidently that's not working. Using more modern syntax in the actual Angular files might be a problem for browser support, and I guess there's no transpilation in their build process.

Comment: What are you using to build your project? Webpack?

Comment: @jonrsharpe @Cully  i'm not sure if i have a transpilation process set up. 
 what i know fo sure, the project doesn't use webpack! i suppose it doesn't use babel as well (no file babel.config.json exist in the project)
There is a build task in the gulp file but i don't know if is related to the javascript transpilation, or others companion languages as scss or others thinks
so, lets assume i don't have any transpilation sistem, what is the easiest way to enable the use of `.map`?
installing webpack with its default? and later? should  i modify the gulp file to insert this phase?

Comment: Again, the problem isn't using map it's using *arrow functions*.